# VBA for moving file from one Sharepoint folder to another in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I want to write (or find) some VBA code that basically moves an XL sheet from one Sharepoint folder to another Sharepoint folder when someone clicks on the macro button.

The only solution that I found until now is that I need to map the Sharepoint link into local folder and then use .FSO code but this isn't working for me since there is no administrator access to do that for security reasons.

The only code which I found out until now is below

```
Function ConvertPath(path) As String
  ConvertPath = Replace(path, " ", "%20")
  ConvertPath = Replace(ConvertPath, "/", "\")
  ConvertPath = Replace(ConvertPath, "http:", "")
End Function
Private Sub Approve_Click()
  Dim sDocPath As String
  Dim sDocPathConv As String
  Dim sFileName As String
  Dim sTargetPath As String
  Dim sSourcePath As String
  Dim fso As FileSystemObject
  Set fso = New FileSystemObject ' CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  sDocPath = ThisWorkbook.path
  sFileName = "WorkBook.xlsx"

  sDocPathConv = ConvertPath(sDocPath)

  sSourcePath = sDocPathConv & "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxx/" & sFileName
  Debug.Print "Source: " & sSourcePath     
  sTargetPath = sDocPathConv & "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxxx/" & sFileName
  Debug.Print "Target: " & sTargetPath
  fso.CopyFile sSourcePath, sTargetPath, True
End Sub
```

And even this code is not working as it always gives an error which says "Path not found". I am not at all familiar with VBA programming.

Comment: Can you better explain what "this isn't working for me since there is no administrator access to do that for security reasons" means? Do you have write read access to the shared folder? Can you manually copy the file from one shared folder to the other?

Comment: `sTargetPath = sDriveLetter "\https:\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\" & sFileName` is a path that can't be found. Try `sTargetPath = sDriveLetter & "\https:\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\" & sFileName`

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, thanks for viewing. Yes, I can manually copy the file from one folder to another in sharepoint but when I try to map network drive the same folder link, it doesn't allow me to do so

Comment: Hi @Variatus, Currently it is giving me compile error in the code ´´´´sDocPath = ConvertPath(sDocPath)```` It says Sub or Fun not defined. Can you help?

Comment: Try, please, [this](https://collab365.community/map-a-sharepoint-document-library-as-a-network-drive/) way of mapping...

Comment: Okay, from what I have understood, do I need to define "ConvertPath" as String since it is giving me an error in this code line?

Comment: I have updated the code now but now it gives me an error which says "Bad file name or number" in the line ""fso.CopyFile sSourcePath, sTargetPath, True""" Can you help me with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try syncing the SharePoint to OneDrive in Windows Explorer. Then code below should work.

Will also need Reference: Microsoft Scripting Runtime

```vb
Public Function strDisplayID() As String
    strDisplayID = Environ("USERNAME")
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton_Click()

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fileLocation As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    fileLocation = "C:\Users\" & strDisplayID & "\YourPath\YourFile".pdf"
    fso.MoveFile fileLocation

End Sub
```